# crash while accessing the std::string of a class

Tags: c++, linux, stdstring, coredump

I have the following coredump.

```
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0xb5b1c2f8 in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) ()
   from /arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc_m/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#0  0xb5b1c2f8 in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) ()
   from /arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc_m/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#1  0x00964f5c in Qct::OamClientUtil::getRsp (this=<value optimized out>)
at /Agent/include/oamClientUtil.hpp:92
#2  0x00902118 in MapPM::sendCollect (this=0xb4af9928) at /gent/src/mapPM.cc:557
#3  0x00921dc0 in Agent::handlePMCollectReq (this=<value optimized out>, buf=0xb335ccb0)
at /Agent/src/Agent.cc:5671
#4  0x0095deb4 in AgentRxHandler (handle=<value optimized out>, buf=0xb335ccb0)
at /Agent/src/uslAgent.cc:398
#5  0x0080f364 in uslDCTEntry (dct=20401048) at /usl/src/lcid/uslDCT.cc:253
#6  0x009c867c in TASK::taskEntryPoint (params=0x1375098) at /emvxworks/taskLib.cpp:224
#7  0x009c7bbc in pthreadw_taskentry (arg=<value optimized out>) at /emvxworks/pthread_wrapper.cpp:786
#8  0xb59a6120 in start_thread (arg=0xb4aff460) at pthread_create.c:307
#9  0xb592e9f8 in nfsservctl ()
from /CodeSourcery/4.6.3-2012.03-57/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc_m/lib/libc.so.6
Backtrace stopped: frame did not save the PC
```

I am quite confused how a simple string is causing the crash.

Since the code is pretty big I will paste the relevant classes for now. Will add more if needed.

```
/Agent/include/oamClientUtil.hpp:92

37    class OamClientUtil
38    {
39    public:
40        OamClientUtil();
41
42        virtual
43        ~OamClientUtil();
44
45        
46        void
47        initOamProxyConn();
48
49        void
50        setBatch(
51            OamClients& batch
52        );
53
54        /// load oam transactions from a file
55        /// and convert them to a list of oam client transactions
56        bool
57        loadTrxFromFile(
58            std::string& batchfilename
59        );
60
61        /// actual processing the list of transactions
62        MgmtResult
63        run();
64
65        bool
66        isGood();
67
68        /// return the dryrun flag
69        bool
70        isDryrun();
71
72        /// set the dryrun flag
73        bool
74        isDryrun(bool flag);
75
76        const OamErrorString&
77        errorString() const;
78
79        
80        void
81        initRsp() {
82            getRsp_ = "";
83        }
84        void
85        initKeyRsp() {
86            getKeysRsp_ = "";
87        }
88
89        
90        std::string
91        getRsp() {
92            return getRsp_;
93        }
94        std::string
95        getKeysRsp() {
96            return getKeysRsp_;
97        }
98        bool
99        getKeysLast() {
100            return getKeysLast_;
101        }
102    private:
103        static const unsigned REQ_TIMEOUT_SECS = 10;
104
105        /// send get request
106        MgmtResult
107        sendGetReq(
108            OamClientTrxPtr trx
109        );
110
111        /// send getKeys request
112        MgmtResult
113        sendGetKeysReq(
114            OamClientTrxPtr trx
115        );
116        /// send set request
117        MgmtResult
118        sendSetReq(
119            OamClientTrxPtr trx
120        );
121
122        /// send clear request
123        MgmtResult
124        sendClearReq(
125            OamClientTrxPtr trx
126        );
127
128        /// process the list of transactions
129        MgmtResult
130        processTransactionList(
131            OamClientTrxList& trxlist ///< The list of transaction to be processed
132        );
133
134        /// process one transaction
135        MgmtResult
136        processTransaction(
137            OamClientTrxPtr trx ///< The transaction to be processed
138        );
139
140        /// print content of one transaction
141        void
142        printRequests(
143            OamClientTrxPtr trx
144        );
145
146        void
147        indCallback(
148            unsigned int msgId,
149            QctUint8_t* indMsgBuffer,
150            unsigned int indMsgBufferLength);
151
152        
153        static ProvisioningPtr
154        initProvisioningPtr();
155
156        
157        static MgmtXmlPtr
158        initMgmtXmlPtr();
159
160        QmiClient qmiClient_;
161        MgmtXmlPtr mgmtXmlPtr_;
162        OamClients batch_;
163        SerialStreamFixedBuf<QMI_FSM_OAM_CLIENT_MAX_LENGTH_V04> sstream_;
164        QctUint16_t trxid_;
165
166        std::string batchfilename_;
167        bool isDryrun_; 
168        bool isGood_;
169        QctUint32_t oamSessionId_;
170        OamErrorString errorMsg_;
171        std::string getRsp_; 
172        std::string getKeysRsp_; 
173        bool getKeysLast_; 
174        ProvisioningPtr provisioningPtr_;
175    };
176




#2  0x00902118 in MapPM::sendCollect (this=0xb4af9928) at /Agent/src/mapPM.cc:557



    549Qct::MgmtResult MapPM::sendCollect()
    550{
    551    clUtil_.initRsp();
    552    clUtil_.setBatch(oamClients_);
    553    Qct::MgmtResult mr = clUtil_.run(); // process every transaction in oamClients_
    554    if (mr == Qct::MGMT_RESULT_FAIL) {
    555      //return Qct::MGMT_RESULT_FAIL;
    556    }
    557    return makePMFile(clUtil_.getRsp());
    558
    }

clUtil_ is object of Qct::OamClientUtil  
    Qct::OamClientUtil clUtil_;

/Agent/src/Agent.cc:5671

    5671    Qct::MgmtResult result = mapPM.sendCollect();

/Agent/src/uslAgent.cc:398

    400      case OAM_AGENT_PMSETUP:
    401          oamAgent.handlePMSetupReq(buf);
    402          break;
```

Comment: You should strip your code down to an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to make a more reasonable question. As a bonus, it's also a decent debugging technique, and you might find the problem on the way. And we would at least need to see `/Agent/src/uslAgent.cc:398`.

Comment: "*I am quite confused how a simple string is causing the crash.*" -- Easy.  The object that contains the string may be invalid.

Comment: @BoBTFish I felt its something to do with the order of declaration, so I posted the whole class otherwise to start with it was a snipet.

Comment: `std::string` allocates on the heap and it is important the correct Runtime library is used, e.g. both /MT or both /MD

Comment: @punith Even if you changed the order of declaration and noticed a difference in the way the app worked, unless it is an issue with initialization of the object (where order makes a difference, especially if you write code in the member initialization list that depends on the order), then this only indicates that you've corrupted memory somewhere.  Moving lines of code around and having different behavior is a sign of such corruption.

Comment: @JensMunk It looks like the OP is using something other than Visual Studio.  However your point is correct in that the heap used by `std::string` across executable modules must be the same if that string is manipulated by one or more modules.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You are right. On linux, you have the same issue. The C runtime must be the same. if everything is installed using the package system, it should not be an issue.

Comment: The `string` is not the problem.  That object is part of a larger object, which has a problem `this` pointer.  See stack frame #1, where `this` has been optimized out.  I'd focus on that.

Comment: All that being said, @punith: Your code design could be better. Init functions, getters, member variables named `get<something>_` after their getter functions...?!?

Comment: Is `clUtil_`s constructor ever called?

Comment: @Adam Yes Base class of mapPM has this object as protected.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there should be any valid reason for your program to crash at this point -- that is assuming that;

- All the code have been compiled with the same compiler
- The header files are not compiled differently in different files (i.e. you didn't forget to recompile something after you changed a header file).

I think you most likely have a memory corruption somewhere else and it shows up (by bad luck) when you accesses this class.   Try to use a tool like valgrind or similar to track down anything bad being done by the rest of your code.